# Automatically ranking data in spreadsheet by date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm currently using Google Sheets and want to find a way automatically to rank by date the data that I put in. I have two sheets:

- one in which I book a job at a particular post code and the date that they're expecting someone to arrive (all new jobs are added as a new entry).
- On the second spreadsheet however, I want to see the list of the postcodes in order of when they're expecting someone to arrive.

Is it possible to create a spreadsheet whereby the data I enter into the first sheet gets automatically added and ranked in the second in the manner described above?

(I know you can copy and paste before sorting by date but it'd be more efficient if it was automated.)

Comment: Not an Excel question - please don't use that tag for google spreadsheet questions

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=query(Sheet1!A:B, "select * where B is not NULL order by B asc")
```

This puts the earliest dates (Column B) first and only lists entries that have a date.